# Catch fails in SQL when failure is induced on purpose

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

Catch fails in Stored Procedure when failure is induced on purpose.

I am trying to test the catch portion in my Stored Procedure by changing a column name after I create the stored procedure. But the catch never gets executed and it fails at the line where the error is. Any ideas on what I could be doing wrong?

Steps to reproduce:

```
* Create Table ErrorTest 

    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ErrorTest](

        [ErrorTest] [varchar](50) NULL

    ) ON [PRIMARY]

* Create Stored Procedure TestError

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @EmailMessage AS VARCHAR(5000)

    BEGIN

        BEGIN TRY

            SELECT  ErrorTest FROM ErrorTest

        END TRY

        BEGIN CATCH             
            declare @error int, @message varchar(4000), @xstate int;
            select @error = ERROR_NUMBER()
                 , @message = ERROR_MESSAGE()
                 , @xstate = XACT_STATE();

        SET @EmailMessage = 'Failure ' + CHAR(13) + 'Error Code: '+ CAST(@error AS VARCHAR)  + CHAR(13) + @message
            EXEC    [leads].[usp_SendEmail]
                    @Mysubject = N'FAILURE!',
                    @Mybody = @EmailMessage,
                    @Myrecipients = N'me@email.com'                                     
        END CATCH
        END
```

- Change the name of the column in step 1 from
  [ErrorTest] to [ErrorTest2]
- This will make the stored procedure fail with error

  Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure TestError, Line 8
  Invalid column name 'ErrorTest'.
- The catch never gets executed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The SP is never executes - it simply **not compiles** - thus there is nothing to execute

Rewrite your TRY section in a way like this and try once more:

```
BEGIN TRY

    EXEC('SELECT  ErrorTest FROM ErrorTest')

END TRY
```